# Detect Square shape in image with PHP or JS

Tags: javascript, php

I want to make a OMR sheet Answer Checker. How to detect square block on sheet?

Answer (score 0):

see the following PHP posts :

[how to detect shape in a image with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427836/how-to-detect-shape-in-a-image-with-php)

[How to detect position of shape in image PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042684/how-to-detect-position-of-shape-in-image-php)

And see GD library :

http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php